# Sorting an ArrayList based on the result of a method

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, comparator

### I have these objects in an ArrayList:

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    ...
    private ArrayList<Double> coordinates;
    ...
}
```

### And I have a method in my main class that outputs the distance between 2 points called :

```
p2pDistance(Foo x, Foo b)
```

What I am trying to do is sort the list according to the value given by calling `p2pDistance(root,elem)` root being an instance of Foo not in the original List.

### My attempt was to do the following:

```
data.sort((o1, o2) -> (int) p2pDistance(root, o1));
```

*(or the equivalent non-lambda expression):*

```
data.sort(new Comparator<Foo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        return (int) Main.this.p2pDistance(root, o1);
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't end up working. 
My guess would be making a method that cycles through the List and retains the smallest result but I wanted to know why my method doesn't work and if there still is an elegant solution to this. *(without having to loop through the list and find the lowest result)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `data.sort((o1, o2) -> (int) p2pDistance(root, o1));` you are not actually comparing `o1` and `o2`. You're returning a distance as a result of compare, while comparator should return

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Try to use `data.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(x -> p2pDistance(x, root)));`

`.comparingDouble`'s argument is `ToDoubleFunction<? super T> keyExtractor` which allows you to map any object to a double value.

Comment: Thank you  very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`Comparable` wants one of three results:

- a **negative** value - `o1 < o2`
- a **zero** value - `o1 = o2`
- a **positive** value - `o1 > o2`

Presumably, your `distance` function is always returning a positive value. So you're likely just reverse ordering the points.

What it looks like you want is to compare the distances of both points to the root, not just `o1`. So, something like

```
return p2pDistance(root, o1) - p2pDistance(root, o2);
```

This will sort the `WadingPool` objects in the list by their distance to the root point (whatever that is).